# What prevents a hacker from publishing a newer version of a package to NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

What prevents a hacker from cloning a NodeJS repo from github, adding some malicious code, incrementing the version as a patch, and running `npm publish`?

It doesn't look like the NPM docs say anything about authenticating the identity of the person running `npm publish`.

I cloned a repo and incremented the version and ran `npm publish --dry-run` and it didn't complain that it wouldn't publish.

Comment: This is actually a real problem. See https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/08/02/typosquatting_npm/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NPM does restrict who can push code to your published package, but that's not to say someone can't do this without your knowledge. There's been a few cases so far where stolen credentials have presumably been employed.

You could experiment by creating a package, then attempt to push to it from another computer without the necessary credentials. You'll see what measures are in place to prevent that.